pyOptSparseDriver option hist_file
Good afternoon, colleagues.
Can you help me? I'm trying to set hist_file option to the pyOptSparseDriver with the following code:
prob.driver = om.pyOptSparseDriver(hist_file='OptView.hst')

I get an error:

KeyError: "pyOptSparseDriver: Option 'hist_file' cannot be set because
it has not been declared."

What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately, I couldn't find any information about using this option in the manual. I think it's a file extension issue. What extension is supported?
And do I understand correctly that in order to use the hotstart_file option I must specify the hist_file?

What version of OpenMDAO are you using? Is it possible you have a version older than 3.28?  This option didn't exist in earlier versions.
You can check your version by issuing the following command: openmdao --version.
See the options for the current version (3.36.0) here: https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.36.0/features/building_blocks/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.html?highlight=hotstart
